# Elastic phrase prefix working phrase isnt

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to return all documents that contain a string in the userName & documentName.

Data:

```
{
  "userName" : "johnwick",
  "documentName": "john",
  "office":{
     "name":"my_office"
  }
},
{
  "userName" : "johnsnow",
  "documentName": "snowy",
  "office": {
     "name":"Abraham deVilliers"
  }
},
{
  "userName" : "johnnybravo",
  "documentName": "bravo",
  "office": {
     "name":"blabla"
  }
},
{
  "userName" : "moana",
  "documentName": "disney",
  "office": {
     "name":"deVilliers"
  }
},
{
  "userName" : "stark",
  "documentName": "marvel",
  "office": {
     "name":"blabla"
  }
}
```

I can perform an exact string match with:

```
}   
  _source": [ "userName", "documentName"],    
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query":       "johnsnow",
      "fields":      [ "userName", "documentName"]
    }
  }
}
```

This successfully returns:

```
{
  "userName" : "johnsnow",
  "documentName": "snowy",
  "office": {
     "name":"Abraham deVilliers"
  }
}
```

If i use `type: phrase_fix` with `john` i also get returned successfully 3 results.

But then i try with:

```
{   
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query":       "ohn",  // <---- match all docs that contain 'ohn'
      "type":        "phrase_prefix"
      "fields":      [ "userName", "documentName"]
    }
  }
}
```

Zero results are returned.

Comment: so what is your requirement, you want to match docs containg `ohn` ? can you share you mapping and expected documents?

Comment: Just updated with _source: [ "userName", "documentName"] as i only want these columns returned to. Yes, i want to match docs containing ohn. So from the example dataabove, it would be first 3 docs as ohn is contained within all of them.

Comment: @OamPsy tested it with few of your sample data, please try and let me know if you face any issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the infix search and you need to have [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) with a [search time analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html) to achieve that.

**Complete example with your sample data**

**Index mapping and setting**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete_filter": {
                    "type": "Ingram",  --> note this
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 10
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "autocomplete_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "index.max_ngram_diff" : 10 --> this you can reduce based on your requirement.
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "userName": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "documentName": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample your docs and then use the same search query, I indexed only first and last doc for brevity and it returned me first doc

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "infix",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 5.7100673,
        "_source": {
          "userName": "johnwick",
          "documentName": "john"
        }
      }
    ]
```